# What's the best way to reduce latency on downstream in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I'm using netty 5.0 and find out that when downstream action is initiated by non-IO thread, it takes few hundreds microseconds to IO thread take the task. Below is the measurement code. I measure the time in two places, one in the non-IO thread and one in the IO thread (Actually, in the encoder outbound handler). In the non-IO thread, the latency is around 200 ~ 300 microseconds while in IO thread, the latency is only 50 ~ 100 nano seconds. Is there anyway to reduce the latency of context switching to sub microseconds?

```
ChannelFuture f = b.bind();
...
ChannelPromise cp = f.channel().newPromise();
long currentNano = System.nanoTime();
cp.addListener(() -> (System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - currentNano));
cp.channel().writeAndFlush(obj);
```

I'm using disruptor pattern in other parts of the codes and it can do object passing between threads below microsecond, so I want to do this same in the netty.

Comment: I am interested to see what others have to say about this :).  The first thing I will say is that Netty does not use disruptor internally. So in the worst case lets see what potential time consuming operations you may encounter...I can see a few `synchronized` blocks that you may be hitting in [addListener](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.java#L142) and in [setSuccess](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.java#L501).

Comment: In addition to the `synchronized ` block the notification mechanism may also be a [notifyAll](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.java#L512) followed by a [Runnable being scheduled in the executor](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.java#L579).  While disruptor tends to go to great lengths to avoid context switching you may be more prone to this in Netty.

Comment: It looks like the a best case scenario is to ensure the promise is completed in while the [executor.inEventLoop()](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise.java#L556) method is true when the promise is completed. This may avoid scheduling a task to notify listeners.